# Linking ViewController and Scene to Show Ads (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

So I was following this tutorial to show a `banner ad` http://insaneplatypusgames.com/2016/03/29/adding-admob-banners-to-spritekit-games/

And the code it provided was pretty straightforward. I am looking to add an ad at the beginning of my app, at the Main Menu.

I get to the last step,

```
// Linking view controller and scene to show ads
scene.ViewController = self
```

and I get an error:

> Value of type MainMenuScene has no member 'ViewController' - Did you
>   mean inutViewController? And I didn't mean inputViewController.

You might need more information but I am not sure what so just as I can include it.

Comment: Or if anyone knows another tutorial they can direct me to that would be awesome as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scene.viewController = self` **not** `scene.ViewController = self`

viewController is member variable having type `GameViewController` in your GameScene.(according to your tutorial)

Comment: Thank you I changed it to scene.viewController and I get the same error, but now with the corrected  type. Do you suggest anything else?